# How to Navigate to a new screen using a floating action button

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am trying to move to another screen from my homepage using the floating action button but unfortunately, the floating action button is not working. On tapping the button the next screen does not appear the console is showing context issues but I have been unable to go around it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kitchen/Screen/kitchenscreen.dart';
import 'package:kitchen/Screen/FoodScreen.dart';


void main ()
{
  runApp(myapp());
}

class myapp extends StatelessWidget
{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold
        (
        backgroundColor:Colors.white60,
        appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: const Text('Teach'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed:(){},
             icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),)
        ] ,
      ),
      body:const  Center(
        child: Text('Add Content here'),
      ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>FoodScreen()),);},
          backgroundColor:Colors.green,
          child:const  Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FoodScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  const FoodScreen({Key ? key}) :super(key:key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return const Scaffold(
        body:Center(child:Text('hello')));
  }
}
```

I was trying to get a screen after tapping the Floating action button but unfortunately on tapping the screen doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, it's possible that the context you are using in the `FloatingActionButton`'s `onPressed` function is not associated with a `Navigator`, and the navigation might not work as expected, therefore you have to provide proper `context` using a `navigatorKey` or a `Builder` widget.

You can use a `Builder` widget like this:

```dart
...
floatingActionButton: Builder(
  builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FoodScreen()),
      );
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
),
...
```

Comment: thankyou so much it worked ...would you mind explaining what i did wrong am a beginer in flutter..I would relly apreciate more insights

Comment: @Allan I have updated the answer. Please accept the the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `context` you pass to `Navigator.push` is wrong. It is the context of `myapp`, which isn't stay inside your `Scaffold` widget.

If you want to use `Navigator`, then you must pass the `context` that stay inside Scaffold. Try `Builder` to have the `context` stay inside `Scaffold`:

```
Builder(
        builder: (builderContext) => FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              builderContext,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builderContext) => FoodScreen()),
            );
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different methods to solve your issues let's discuss one by one.

1. First method is optional arguments means you can't give context and inn that you just put _ for the optional argument.

```
   Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FoodScreen()),
      );
```

- Another is the best option which is context free navigation and I personally use this because at some point you need to access context but context is not available. I will show you proper method and how you can implement in your program step by step.
- First let's create one file and setup our context free navigation file below is the code.

**navigator_service.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationService {
  NavigationService._internal();
  static final NavigationService instance = NavigationService._internal();

  late final NavigatorState currentState = navigationKey.currentState!;

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  dynamic goBack([dynamic popValue]) {
    return navigationKey.currentState!.pop(popValue);
  }

  BuildContext get context => currentState.context;

  void navigateToScreen(String page, {dynamic arguments}) =>
      navigationKey.currentState?.pushNamed(page, arguments: arguments);

  Future<void> replaceScreen(Widget page, {dynamic arguments}) async =>
      navigationKey.currentState!.pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => page,
        ),
      );

  void popToFirst() =>
      navigationKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
}
```

- Now in above file we define all the methods for push, pop and replace screen. Now your work is very easy whenever you want to navigate to another screen just replace your code.

```
 NavigationService.instance.navigateToScreen(Your Route Name),
```

But you need to create route generator for this and work will be easy.

**route_generator.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: cast_nullable_to_non_nullable

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tmdb_movie_app/routes/routes.dart';


class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const SelectPages(),
        );
      case '/Your Route':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const HomePage(),
        );
      
      default:
        return errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              'Error',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
          ),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('No Routes Found'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```